# Jquery animate problem in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've been trying to recreate an effect I saw on another website and while it looks like it mostly works I'm not having a problem in Google Chrome. The effect is when you hover over an image thumbnail it comes up with 3 icons which link to various options.

The problem comes in Chrome when there are more thumbnails than are visible in one window. You hover over the ones in the window without problem. Though if you scroll down to ones that weren't initially visible in the window there seems to be some bug that locks the animation up. It works fine if you move slowly, but quicker movements seem to pause the animation on one thumbnail (you don't have to move that fast to replicate it, I've tried it on three different machines). If you hover back over the ones that were visible it works fine still. If I maximise the window so they are all visible then again it is fine.

Works fine in IE9 and FF4 on all the thumbnails regardless of window size. I've been messing around with .stop changing the true,false options but that doesn't seem to have much effect. This is my first attempts at using jquery other than using pre written scripts, any help is appreciated. From searching I've seen others having a problem with Chrome, though nothing concrete that has been able to help.

http://kineticcomplex.com/jquerytest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working in Chrome12 for me. I've had a few problems in the past with `hover()` in Chrome (and `position()` as well). I've read that Webkit is just too fast sometimes. <strike>Maybe that is what is happening here? I couldn't really see what the problem is with hover() in this case though. However using a different strategy seems to be better in Chrome.</strike> I changed the class to the actual `<img>`, rather than the outer `<div>` otherwise the animation was starting in the blank space around the images and I moved the background shadow before the animation to make the highlight quicker, i.e. not having to wait for the animation to start.

**Edit:** It might be a *float* bug in Chrome. If you replace the `float:left` style in the `.et_pt_gallery_entry` with `display:inline-block` then the hover() works. I've left the updated hover() code below anyway, since it is a bit cleaner. I try and avoid float whenever possible. Had many issues over the years with floating elements! Hope this fixes it for you.

```
$(function(){
    $('.et_pt_item_image').hover(function(){
        $('.zoom-icon, .more-icon, .map-icon', this).css({opacity:0, visibility:'visible'});
        $('img', this).css({backgroundColor:'#ddd', borderColor:'#bbb'},400);
        $('a.zoom-icon', this).stop().animate({opacity: 1, left: 40}, 400);
        $('a.more-icon', this).stop().animate({opacity: 1, left: 105}, 400);
        $('a.map-icon', this).stop().animate({opacity: 1, left: 170}, 400);
    }, function(){
        $('img', this).css({backgroundColor:'#fff', borderColor:'#e5e5e5'},400);
        $('a.zoom-icon', this).stop().animate({opacity: 0, left: 31}, 400);
        $('a.more-icon', this).stop().animate({opacity: 0, left: 105}, 400);
        $('a.map-icon', this).stop().animate({opacity: 0, left: 180}, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, getting a double flicker effect using that. Once when the mouse is over the thumbnail and then it goes again when you move the mouse onto one of the three icons.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing that too. Guess I was a bit too quick to answer! Working on it :-)

Comment: Thanks appreciate it, if it is any help it works fine on the original I saw it on: http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Webly/gallery/ he uses .hover rather than mouseover.

Comment: As you said you are using Chrome 12 I just put that on my laptop to see if it had been fixed due to that. I'm still getting the original issue of the ones rendered off screen not working properly. (in versions 10 and 12) Pretty odd problem.

Comment: Updated my answer. Looks like it is a CSS `float` property issue.

Comment: andyb you sir are a genius! it works with the mouseover using inline-block as well. Thanks a lot for your help didn't know there was a float bug in Chrome, hadn't seen using inline-block before either. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using different mouse events, such as mouseenter/leave, or mouseover/out?